# mdadm - software raid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I set up a small raid based Ubuntu 11.04 server machine and have just received this email from it. How can i verify or check this ?

Richard

> This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm  running on
>   godzilla
>
> A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md/0.
>
> It could be related to component device /dev/sda1.
>
> Faithfully yours, etc.
>
> P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:
>
> Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5]
>   [raid4] [raid10]  md0 : active raid5 sda10 sdb1[1] sdd1[3]
>   sdc1[2]
>         2927135232 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]
>         [>....................]  check =  2.2% (21655188/975711744) finish=4419.8min speed=3597K/sec
>
> **&> cat /proc/mdstat** Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0]
>   [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] md0 : active raid5 sda10
>   sdb1[1] sdd1[3] sdc1[2]
>         2927135232 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]
>
> unused devices:
>
> **cat /proc/mdstat** Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1]
>   [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
>   md0 : active raid5 **sda1[0]F** sdb1[1]sdd1[3] sdc1[2]
>         2927135232 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]
>
> unused devices:
>
> **Dmsg**
>   [775549.274966] md/raid:md0: Disk failure on sda1, disabling device.
>   [775549.274967] md/raid:md0: Operation continuing on 3 devices.
>   [775549.280021] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310408 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280028] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310416 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280031] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310424 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280035] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310432 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280039] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310440 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280043] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310448 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280047] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310456 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280051] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310464 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280055] md/raid:md0: read error not correctable (sector
>   43310472 on sda1
>   ). [775549.280226] ata7: EH complete [775549.316567] ata7.00:
>   exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x300000 action 0x6 [775549.319133]
>   ata7.00: BMDMA stat 0x45 [775549.321658] ata7: SError: { Dispar BadCRC
>   } [775549.324237] ata7.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
>   [775549.326754] ata7.00: cmd 25/00:f8:28:ed:94/00:03:02:00:00/e0 tag 0
>   dma 52019
>   2 in [775549.326757]          res 51/84:48:78:7f:2e/84:00:03:00:00/e0
>   Emask 0x10 (ATA
>   bus error) [775549.331806] ata7.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
>   [775549.334350] ata7.00: error: { ICRC ABRT } [775549.336890] ata7:
>   hard resetting link [775549.336895] ata7: nv: skipping hardreset on
>   occupied port [775549.340260] md: md0: data-check done.
>   [775549.804062] ata7: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
>   [775549.844352] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/33 [775549.844390] ata7:
>   EH complete [775549.936450] RAID conf printout: [775549.936456]  ---
>   level:5 rd:4 wd:3 [775549.936460]  disk 0, o:0, dev:sda1
>   [775549.936463]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdb1 [775549.936465]  disk 2, o:1,
>   dev:sdc1 [775549.936507]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sdd1 [775549.936557] RAID
>   conf printout: [775549.936559]  --- level:5 rd:4 wd:3 [775549.936562] 
>   disk 1, o:1, dev:sdb1 [775549.936564]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdc1
>   [775549.936567]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sdd1

**sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0**

> /dev/md0:
>           Version : 1.2   Creation Time : Sat Jan  1 14:43:44 2005
>        Raid Level : raid5
>        Array Size : 2927135232 (2791.53 GiB 2997.39 GB)   Used Dev Size : 975711744 (930.51 GiB 999.13 GB)    Raid Devices : 4   Total Devices
>   : 4
>       Persistence : Superblock is persistent
>
> ```
> Update Time : Sun Feb  5 19:17:41 2012
>       State : clean, degraded  Active Devices : 3 Working Devices : 3  Failed Devices : 1   Spare Devices : 0
>
>      Layout : left-symmetric
>  Chunk Size : 512K
>
>        Name : godzilla:0  (local to host godzilla)
>        UUID : 7c2be5e4:25e338e5:b575b8cd:83896caf
>      Events : 657
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>    0       0        0        0      removed
>    1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
>    2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
>    3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
>
>    0       8        1        -      faulty spare   /dev/sda1
> ```

Comment: Also, is there a way to find out which HDD/Sda1 is attached to which SATA port on the MotherBoard ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the output of 'dmesg' as well as the file /var/log/syslog. There might be hints concerning problems with /dev/sda1.

The hard disk could have crashed but it also could just be a cable that's not plugged in well (SATA cables are just... not that awesome). See whether the device is still online, maybe it is available using a different name like /dev/sde1 or whatever is the next free name in your system. As mentioned, I'd check dmesg/syslog, SMART, too. Maybe the cable just has to be plugged in properly or has to be replaced. In most cases you can re-add the disk to your RAID array - I'd only use those commands if the problem really has to do with broken cables or something comparable, i.e. no "real" hard disk failure.

```
mdadm --fail /dev/mdX /dev/sdX # set the disk faulty
mdadm -r /dev/mdX /dev/sdX # remove faulty disk
mdadm --re-add /dev/mdX /dev/sdX # re-add disk
```

Disclaimer: No guarantee, you should have backups, this will rebuild your RAID array - for that time there is no redundancy, etc.

Comment: $ sudo mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/sda1

mdadm: set /dev/sda1 faulty in /dev/md0

$ sudo mdadm -r /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sda1 from /dev/md0
$ sudo mdadm --re-add /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
**mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sda1 to /dev/md0 is not possible**         Why whould it not be possible ?